# Can an implement held in Far Hand or Mage Hand (et. al.) be used with powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, implements

Scenario:  A substance has been encountered which appears to augment damage done by weapons and, perhaps, implements.  However, this substance appears to be harmful to those who come in direct physical contact with it.

For most weapon users, this is not an issue since they will simply coat the blade/tip of the weapon and leave the handle clean.  However, for some implement users (particularly orb users) this is not a viable solution.

Some, if not most, implement users (particularly Wizards and Psions) have abilities (like *Mage Hand* and *Far Hand*) that let them move and manipulate objects without being in physical contact with them.

Could these powers be used to wield an implement for use with powers as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No**,

Mage Hand can do the following things:

- **Minor Action**: The hand picks up or manipulates an object weighing 20 pounds or less. It can hold only one object at a time.
- **Move Action:** The hand moves up to 5 squares in any direction, carrying the object it holds.
- **Free Action:** The hand drops the object it is holding.

(Far Hand is similar)

You would need wording similar to **Dancing**<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=161)</sup> weapons,  **"as if you were holding it yourself "**  There is no wording on Mage Hand to imply that the object is to be treated as if the caster was holding it.  The first sentence of the glossary definition of **Implement**<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=69)</sup> is:

> Implements are items wielded by certain characters to channel their powers.

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the case.  As a sidenote, we've houseruled that for this particular scenario it is permissible.  Of course, the Far Hand would have to remain in my square - I couldn't use it to have my powers originate from a square 50 feet away.

Comment: @Iszi Houseruling is always cool if it makes your group happy!  Just be careful to offer to give it up if you sense that anyone thinks it is overpowered and your group desires balance.

Comment: Addendum to the houserule for future reference, in case anyone is interested:  The use of Far Hand/Mage Hand to wield an implement is not permitted to "free up" whatever hand would normally hold the implement.  It's as if the Far Hand/Mage Hand is forming a glove of telekinetic or arcane force around your hand, shielding it from whatever it is holding.

Comment: @Iszi - that sounds cool, and much less likely to get overpowered.  Good call!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer friend: Nope.

In order for ANY implement to work, you must be bearing it, it must be in direct contact with your character. But it must be on YOUR persona, and for you to gain the bonuses, you must HOLD it with your hand.

Answer (score -3):

I would say no if I was the DM in the situation.  Mage hand limited to minor tasks, and shouldn't be able to stack as many spells limit.  i would consider this stacking.  If the character however was to invest in research for making this possible from more accomplished mages you could make an adventure out of it, and hey thats a goal for all DMs.  Now Greater Mage Hand I have seen somewhere before and I would allow it to stack with limits.

Comment: I think you're discussing the wrong edition, mate.

Comment: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/774/how-do-we-get-more-questions-about-things-besides-dd-4e

Comment: This questions is specifically tagged at 4e.

Comment: To elaborate on Simon Withers comment... That meta thread is looking for more *questions* about non-4E topics. This question is about 4E already, so that's what the answers should focus on (as that's what's most likely to help the person who asked the question).

Comment: Cool wont try to encourage those with similar problems in a pointed out wanted more questions for edition any more...makes umm sense?

Comment: Do you mean you think it's appropriate to answer a *topic* with a topical answer, regardless of addition in case someone from a different editions perspective search for the topic?